# How to reconcile this question without knowing how sort(XS) is implemented

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

My teacher has given me the following information to answer a question:
[image]

My question is, how can I accurately answer this without knowing how sort() is implemented? He is not responding to my emails, so I thought I'd post here. Am I correct in assuming we need to know the implementation or runtime of sort in this context?

Comment: By the way, I have already submitted this hw. I answered this question just assuming the sort() algorithm had a runtime of O(n!) and determined "smallest_two" would then also have a runtime of O(n!). It's probably wrong, but I couldn't get a hold of the teacher in time to ask.

Comment: I would tend to agree with your assessment that the properties of sort will drive this. Also, probably besides the point of the exercise, but sorting the list to find the two smallest elements doesn't seem a good use of computer resources. How did you come up with `n!` for sort?

Comment: I just made an assumption that sort() used an algorithm like bogosort,  which has an avg runtime of ```O(n!)```

Comment: Okay, but bogosort is famously bad :)

Comment: lol what if I chose an algorithm with ```O(n^2)``` runtime? would smallest_two also be ```O(n^2)``` maybe that's the teacher's point in asking "what is the limiting consideration", with that consideration being how "sort" is implemented?

Comment: That could very well be.

Comment: I don't understand what the relevance is of returning the two smallest values in order to answer a question about `sort`.

Comment: Should we consider that `sort` may do a bad job that is just good enough to ensure the smallest two values end up at the front of the list?

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the best possible worst case complexity of *any* implementation of `smallest_two`, i.e., how fast can you find the smallest two elements of a list?  The best implementation doesn't sort at all... but who knows?  It's oddly written.

Comment: Also, in a lazy functional language Haskell, `smallest_two` may take O(n) time as written, since only the first two elements of the sort result are evaluated.  I only mention this, because the given code looks Haskellish.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the phrase "best possible worst-case runtime".

Which boils down to, "If you could choose the best sort algorithm possible, what would the worst case performance be?"

And the answer is `O(n log(n))`.